mypy can't infer type of a dictionary value: What's a clean way to still use it as a function argument?
I have a dictionary that I use as my "config". I don't change values, so it could be immutable. I use its values as arguments for functions via key indexing, something like this:
from typing import Union

my_config: dict[str, Union[int, float, str]] = {
    "timeout": 60,
    "precision": 3.14,
    "greeting": "Hello",
}

def my_function(arg: int):
    print(f"The value is: {arg}")

my_function(arg=my_config["timeout"])

Since mypy is a static type checker, it cannot infer the types inside a dictionary. So it will complain:

Argument "arg" to "my_function" has incompatible type "Union[int, float, str]"; expected "int"

What is the proper way to deal with this situation? Some ideas:
from typing import cast
# type cast before call
my_function(arg=int(my_dict["key1"]))
my_function(arg=cast(int, my_dict["key1"]))

Is there more? What is the preferred way to deal with this? Do I have to go back a step and change my approach of using a dict for my_config? Maybe use a truly immutable data type in the first place?

Using cast will satisfy mypy but, obviously, it doesn't help with runtime checking.
If you really want to be sure that your function has been passed an appropriate type then you have to write code that will test at runtime.
Something like this:
type DVAL = int|float|str

my_config: dict[str, DVAL] = {
    "timeout": 60,
    "precision": 3.14,
    "greeting": "Hello",
}

def my_function(arg: DVAL):
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        print(f"The value is: {arg} with type int")
    else:
        raise TypeError("Expected int")

my_function(my_config["timeout"])

